# Turning off other computers in your network using ping and tracerout

Tags: networking

I am recently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have seen a video on YouTube [How to shutdown/restart other computers on your network/wi-fi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0NJF0ASQ2o).

On how to turn off other computers on your network using command in Windows. I would love to do this in my computer Ubuntu. Could any one suggest how I could do that with the steps?

Comment: That simply doesn't work in Ubuntu.

Comment: no way?????? please, i need it so much!!!!

Comment: You can shutdown Linux computers remotely through an SSH session, of course. But I suppose that is not what you want.

Comment: i am sorry but i dont understand the concept of SSH. but if it lets me shut down other computers using my computer, so be it

Comment: how do i shut down other computers using an ssh session

Comment: The other computer should run a SSH service, like `sshd`, which comes with Ubuntu but is (I think) not enabled by default. Then, you need a user account on that machine with `sudo` privileges. From your local computer enter the command `ssh user@remote-computer`, log in with your password, and enter `sudo shutdown -h now` for an immediate shutdown, or `sudo shutdown -r now` for a restart.

Answer (score 4):

You can shutdown the computers remotely via ssh. Make sure you have openssh-server installed on the remote computer you want to connect.

if not then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and after

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server -y
```

Now open the Terminal in the client computer and type the command below for a computer you want to connect to.

`ssh user1@ip-address-of the-computer`  and hit enter.

***note*** : Please note that the user1 is the username and ip-address should be the ip of the host you want to connect to (remote machine in this case)

Now it will ask for the password for user you are trying to access as, on the remote computer.Prompt will ask you if you want to add the ssh key, say Y(es).

You should have something like `user1@ubuntu-server` where *ubuntu-server* is an example of the remote server hostname and *user1* is the user who's account exists on that machine.

Be the root on the server or type

```
sudo init 6    #this will restart the remote computer your are ssh'd in
```

or

```
sudo init 0   #ths will shutdown the remote computer.
```

You can also use **"Putty"** on windows to establish an ssh session.

I hope this helps! Good Luck.

Comment: I heard that ssh in not enabled by default, how can i enable it?

Comment: I already mentioned, when you type `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` this will install and start the sshd daemon. you can also verify by typing `ps aux | grep ssh`

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server -y
```

Here the IP address of the machine you want to remote with is user one

In this case it will ask for the password for user you are trying to access as, on the remote computer. Prompt will ask you if you want to add the ssh key, say Y(es).
type an example like

```
$ user1@ubuntu-server
```

to show user'account in ubuntu

If you need to shutdown the remote machine just type `sudo init 0`
If you want to restart the remote machine just type `sudo init 6`