# Reboot other machine remotely

Tags: networking, server, ssh, shutdown

Apparently one of my Ubuntu 20.04 Servers has crashed.

It still reacts somewhat (I can ping the machine from another server in the same network and I do get the authentification mask upon trying to establish an ssh connection. However, the connection cannot be built up.

As I currently do not have physical access to my office, I would like to attempt to reboot the machine. Either from outside the office network or from another Server within the office network.

Is there a way such as sending a single shutdown -r command without opening a full ssh session?
I have found other questions such as [Turning off other computers in your network using ping and tracerout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581502/turning-off-other-computers-in-your-network-using-ping-and-tracerout) which mention connecting with an ssh client and issuing shutdown -r 0 (not possible for me to open an ssh session)

Comment: If this were possible by default, I think there would be a lot more chaos in data centres around the world … 

Comment: Nope you can not. It is ONLY possible if you set this up and your network card is capable of doing WOL (wake on lan). @matigo I can start and shutdown my systems bij phone. Took some effort to setup but it can be done  ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind yeah, I know it can be done, but it's not an option by default. If it were, botnets all over the planet would be shutting down servers randomly "for the lulz" ...  

Comment: You should perhaps consider installing watchdog or using a LOM (Lights out manager). sometimes ATX boards have them built in.     Otherwise you could buy or use a Raspberry PI as a remote KVM.    That would allow you remote console access and able to do a cntl-alt-del etc.